# Redirect in background without losing focus on current window using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have a string of links like this:

```
<a href="www.google.co.uk">gb version</a>
<a href="www.google.ie">roi version</a>
<a href="www.google.com">non-localised</a>
```

Is there any quick way of making the links open in background without losing focus from the index page using jquery?

Comment: That's what commonly known as a "popunder", and most browsers will have some sort of countermeasure for this.

Comment: Until last chrome update: https://github.com/tuki/js-popunder  But now no more works in chrome 31+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this manually with `CTRL` + `Left-click`. Now you can basically simulate this with [`event.initMouseEvent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-initMouseEvent) which has all the properties of the click event. Including the `CTRL` + `Left-click` event.

The only downside is:

> his method may only be called **before** the MouseEvent has been
>   dispatched

This means you have to cancel the default anchor event and create a custom event which also custom fires.

With `event.preventDefault();` you can cancel the default anchor event from happening:

```
$('a').click(function(event)
{
   event.preventDefault();      
   openNewBackgroundTab($(this));
});
```

Where i will give the clicked element as parameter to the custom event creator(this is used to get the clicked href).

Where we will create a whole new "floating" element, with a custom event and where we manually have to fire the event:

```
function openNewBackgroundTab(elem)
{
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = elem.attr('href');
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");    
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yd8k5/)

*Note that jsFiddle doesn't support external links*

---

Source of this method: [Open a new tab in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background)

Answer (score 1):

Write `target='_blank'`.

```
<a target="_blank" href="www.google.co.uk">gb version</a>
<a target="_blank" href="www.google.ie">roi version</a>
<a target="_blank" href="www.google.com">non-localised</a>
```

Comment: Yes, but target="blank" opens with the focus on the newly opened page, and I have to click on the original window to refocus on it.