# Stay on current page when open new tab in angular js

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
<a class="seecode_button" href="#{{w.CouponID}}" ng-click="newwindow(w)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{w.CouponID}}">CLICK Here</a>

$scope.newwindow = function(w) {
    $window.open(w.LandingPageURL, '_self');
    $window.open('#','_blank');
 };
```

I am try to make when some one click on "CLICK Here" then need to open new window but need stay on current tab.

In my code current tab open in page its ok but popup also gone because of it refresh the page . I am using angular js 1.2.17 and for popup i am using bootstrap.js v3.0.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a new tab in the background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background)

Comment: After communicating with the OP in this exact duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226657/popup-need-to-open-when-new-tab-open-using-angular-js?noredirect=1#comment39294744_25226657 it becomes clear that the OP simply wants to open the new tab in background. Hence, it is a duplicate of the question I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to refresh the page, then use an empty `href` attribute.

Comment: i used href empty but then in new tab open blank