# inactive popup on release

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I've created swf file using flash 8.0 and added button with the following action script:

```
on (release) {
     getURL("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
}
```

**Now** once I click the button, it should after release it trigger window for website  `http://www.google.com`, but this window become the active one while the window where the swf file become inactive, so, I wonder if it can be opened without be the active tab.

**Here is an example**: [test SWF file](http://www.codego.eu/flash).

Click on blue button, it will open new active tab `http://www.google.com` and the tab with the SWF file be inactive!

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background

Answer (score 0):

Change the second argument in your getURL method to `"_self"`. This should open the link in the same tab.

```
on (release) {
     getURL("http://www.google.com", "_self");
}
```