# How can I programmatically make a link create an unfocused tab in Chrome 41?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs, content-disposition, canary-deployment

Currently, I can simulate a 'cmd + click' or a 'ctrl + click' which works in all browsers except ie11.

Google is releasing Chrome 41 soon, which disables the ability to do that. [commit here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/7c3b40a06e92cd393f6e36812399c8976ca93486%5E%21/#F0)

My initial investigation leads me to believe I may be able to force content disposition on a new window (tab), but I don't have the requisite knowledge to know if I should continue experimenting with that, or if I'm going down a rabbit hole.

Comment: Unfortunately, seems like it can't be done

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background