# Have Window Keep Focus After One Click Fires Two Page Redirects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First of all, happy holidays to everyone.

I have an anchor element that fires two page redirects - one through the `href` attribute, one through `jQuery`.

```
<a id="myClick" target="_blank" href="http://www.google.ca">Google</a>

$('#myClick').on('click', function () {
    window.location = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
});
```

This works fine, but the new tab gains focus. I'd like the original tab to keep the focus for the user. I did give `window.focus()` a go but, as assumed, it didn't work.

I also did try working with the fiddle from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background) but it only fired the new tab and the original page (jsfiddle) remained the same URL. [My edited Fiddle from linked answer](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZmvS/643/)

How could I go about having the original tab keep the focus? Is it out of my hands?

Answer (score 0):

You can't open tabs in the background using javascript because this is set in the user's preferences in about:config, which you have no control over. The setting is:

```
browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground=true
```