# Opening new tab when clicking on a link in my website keeping the current tab active

Tags: javascript

I have this code that does what I need. It opens the link in another tab but it moves to the newly opened tab leaving the current tab I'm in. I want it to keep my current tab active and newly opened tab just opened.

```
function loadpopunder() {
                var clicked = false;
                $('a').each(function() {
                    this.onclick = function() {
                        var a = document.createElement("a");
                        a.href = "http://sitetopopeninnewtab.com";
                        if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1)
                        {
                            a.target = "_blank";
                        }
                        if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1)
                        {
//                        var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {'view': window, 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': true, });
                            var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                        }
                        else {
//                        var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {'view': window, 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': true, 'metaKey': true, 'ctrlKey': true});
                            var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                        }
                        evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                true, false, false, false, 0, null);
                        if (clicked == false) {
                            a.dispatchEvent(evt);
                            clicked = true;
                        }
                    }
                });


if(window.location.href == 'http://mymainwebsite.com/'){
    loadpopunder();
}
```

Comment: This is controlled by the settings in your browser, which can not be manipulated using javascript. That means, opening a tab in background using javascript is (for almost all browsers) not possible. There is however a workaround by simulating a `ctrl+click`, which will only work on some browser versions, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background)

Comment: nothing is impossible. Maybe you have to open the tab in the background as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background so you wont loose the focus

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done properly, because you depend on the browser settings. Even when you open a url in a new tab with `target='_blank'`, if the browser is set to open new pages in a pop-up window, you wont get a new tab.

You should check some other SO answer about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript).

You can see on the comments that all browser have different behaviors. 
You can, however, manage new opened windows with [javascript `window` object](http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/JSwindows.html)

Other thing that you can do, is check if the window is focused or not, by using the javascript [visibility api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API).

Hope that helps.