# Open new window in background

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to open new window in background. 
Here is my code:

```
function OpenInNewTab()  
{  
    var myChild= window.open('http://page.pl', '', 'width=,height=,resizable=no');  
    myChild.blur();
    window.focus();
}
```

Usage:

```
<div id="player" style="width:450px;height:300px;">
    <img onclick="OpenInNewTab();" class="button" src="http://page.tv/images/foto.png" />
</div>
```

But it doesn't work. Where is a problem in this code?

Thanks.

Comment: what you mean by background?

Comment: Main window is always activate (focused).

Comment: I hate websites that do this

Comment: I think, it doesn't matter now...

Comment: Somebody else has already solved this problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background

Comment: https://github.com/ptcong/js-popunder

Answer (score -1):

> Copied from Amro: [Open a new tab in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background)

**UPDATE: By version 41 of Google Chrome,** `initMouseEvent` **seemed to have a changed behavior.**

this can be done by simulating `ctrl` + `click` (or any other key/event combinations that open a background tab) on a dynamically generated `a` element with its `href` attribute set to the desired `url`

**In action:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZmvS/5/)

```
function openNewBackgroundTab(){
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = "http://www.google.com/";
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    //the tenth parameter of initMouseEvent sets ctrl key
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                true, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

tested only on chrome