# Open new Firefox tab with JavaScript with expected behavior

Tags: javascript, firefox

When a user clicks a link in my application, I need to "enrich" the clicked URL with some additional context (depending on the interaction) and then proceed as normal.

"As normal" means to set the window location to the new URL, or to open a new tab if a meta key is held while clicking.

This works as expected in all modern browsers except Firefox; in Firefox, the tab is always focused, regardless of what's set in Preferences > Tabs > "When I open a link in a new tab, switch to it immediately".

I can't just let the `MouseEvent` through, because I need to direct to a different URL than that on the clicked `<a href>`; I have to stop propagation of the click event.

In short, how can I get `window.open('url', '_blank')` to respect the user's preferences and any meta keys in Firefox?

EDIT: My question differs from [Open a new tab in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background) in that my need is for Firefox to work like other browsers; Chrome is working fine here. Also, I don't want the target page to always open in the background, I want it to open in another tab on a ctrl+click/cmd+click/middle-mouse click, or in the current window on a non-meta click, and to respect user prefs for opening focused or in the background. Updated the title to address this.

Comment: FYI, I can not stand such behavior and leave the page immediately. It should be up to the user to open new tab or new window.

Comment: @MaxZoom I agree, I want it to be up to the user -- if the user clicks without a meta key, the current window will show the target page; if the user clicks with a meta key, a new tab or window (as specified in the user's browser prefs) will open with the target page, focused or not as specified in the prefs. However, Firefox doesn't honor the focus part; it *always* focuses the new tab. *That* is what I want to fix, so that the user sees the behavior they expect when clicking on any other (i.e. HTML-only) link.

Comment: Here is a jsbin I've been using for testing: http://jsbin.com/huwukejane/3/edit

Comment: @MaxZoom I don't understand -- I have a real, non-imaginary link. I'm handling the 'click' event on that link. I check if there is a meta key (e.g. ctrl, command) held or middle-mouse button clicked; if so, I window.open('url', '_blank') and expect the browser to behave as when any other link is clicked the same way. All browsers except Firefox honor this.

Comment: There was a way to accomplish this: first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background but it stopped working. (actually works for me in chrome, but not in firefox).

Comment: It sounds like you want your link to behave exactly like all links according to the user's browser preferences for click, meta-, ctrl- etc.  In that case, just make a plain `<a href="...">` link. If Firefox has a bug that it doesn't always honor the user's preference, that's _their_ bug — it's not necessary for you to go through contortions to do what you _think_ the user wants.

Comment: @StephenP as I mentioned, in my case I can't make it a plain `<a href>`. Or, perhaps I can...may need to just update the HTML as the user interacts to ensure the correct link. Will look into it.