# How to stay on current window tab when the link opens in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to stay on my current tab though. Is there anyway to not be redirected to that tab? I want the tab to open in the background.

When I do this command below, it opens a new tab and puts me into that url. I want to stay on my original page.

```
window.open('url/','_blank');
```

Comment: This question has been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. It gets me redirected to the new tab. I want that tab to be running in the background.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a new tab in the background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background)

Comment: @NewIsAlwaysBetter the question you linked is not asking the same thing as the OP.

Comment: @rkho I know how to open a new tab in the background. I want to stay on the same page, and not get redirected to the new tab that gets formed.

Comment: It depends on the user, you can't force a behaviour.
If the user opens the link in a new tab, he will stay on the current page, if he follows the link directly, the link target will become the active tab

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you have control over.

That functionality is determined by the browser and only the browser currently.

Comment: So it will open a new tab, but I can't stay on the current page? I always get moved to the new tab. So when I have tab1 | tab 2, I always get moved to tab2. I want to stay on tab1.

Comment: Like I said, that is not possible.