# how to trigger ctrl + click while opening a new tab with window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i am opening a new tab with
 `window.open(URL)` 
In the URL a PDF is being opened
It was working fine until my requirement changed now i have to open the `URL`  in the new tab in such a way that the focus stays on the parent Tab( the opener, the caller).
I have tried different Solutions to trigger and simulate `ctrl + mouse Click` but with no success
starting from `window.focus` and `window.opener.focus`
to

```
function openBackgroundTab(){                           
                window.open('<% =Session("PDFPrintPath")%>');
        }

var e = jQuery.Event("click");
e.ctrlKey = true;
$('#btnFocusOnTab').bind("click",function(e){openBackgroundTab()});
$('#btnFocusOnTab').click();
```

and

```
function openBackgroundTab(){
             var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = '<% =Session("PDFPrintPath")%>';
            var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");    
            evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
            a.dispatchEvent(evt);
            return false;
        }  
document.getElementById("btnFocusOnTab").addEventListener("click", openBackgroundTab, false);
document.getElementById("btnFocusOnTab").click();
```

mentioned in [mentioned as duplicate by @ZocharyDow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background)

if any one can get me a solution, i will praise and preach his geniusness for ages :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background

Comment: @ZacharyDow i have tried this solution but it didn't worked for me. and if u  look at the JSFiddle mentioned in the question, it also doesn't work as described, rather the new tab gets the focus

Comment: You're right. It looks like the functionality was deprecated. Still, it's the same question, just with poor solutions that don't work anymore :)

Comment: Hey, FWIW I found this while trying to figure out how to do this as it seems to be more and more blocked by browser design. http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15001/pop-under-really-that-bad