# Open the two tab with different url in each tab on ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the hyperlink like this in my view:

```
<a ng-switch-when="true" href="" data-ng-click="goToTest(data)">
    {{data.current_state_title}}
</a>
```

On controller my goToTest method using ui-router like this:

```
$scope.goToTask = function (value) {     

    $state.go('my_work.test’, {
        sourceId: value.source_versions[0].source_id, 
        sourceVersionId: value.source_versions[0].id
    });   
};
```

So I need to open this `my_work.test` url in one tab of browser and another url for e.g: `my_work.test_list` into another tab of browser in one click.

I am also new to the angularjs. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Ok I solved the problem of opening the two tab with different url like this :var url= $state.href('my_work.test_list', {sourceId: task.source_versions[0].source_id, sourceVersionId: task.source_versions[0].id});
      var myWindow=window.open(url,'doc_view',''); . But the problem I am facing now is I cannot focus the old window.I do some research  and fond this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background  most of people say solve the same issue I have.But for me it is not working.