# how to make a tabunder in firefox and chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Is there a way to open a tab and then focus to parent without closing child?
I utilize this code to open tab :

```
window.open('http://child.com/');
```

now how to return to parent window without closing any tab?

Updated : look at http://jsfiddle.net/3ZmvS/5/

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", openNewBackgroundTab, false);

function openNewBackgroundTab(){
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = "http://www.google.com/";
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");    
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

this function does not work any more.

Comment: you mean you need to open something in a new tab and stay in the parent/current window?

Comment: yes exactly @ChathurangaTennakoon

Comment: can you try? window.open('http://child.com/', '_blank');

Comment: with this command window.open('child.com/';, '_blank');  new popup opens.  I want to return to parent window after then. @ChathurangaTennakoon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a new tab in the background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background)

Comment: That question is for 4 years ago, and all answers are outdated! , thank you for mention that. @DamiánCastro

Comment: The pop under ads we all loved to hate. How current people do it is open a pop up window to the page they want to be on and set the current page to be the pop under. That is used with page navigation links.