# Opening link in new tab without moving away from the active tab (and without taking user to the new tab) in HTML <a> tag

Tags: html, hyperlink, tabs, anchor, target

When I use `<a href="some url" target="_blank">` and when the user clicks the corresponding link, new tab opens and the user is directed to the new tab.

I want that new tab should open but user should remain on the previous tab only. In other words I want to emulate the <kbd>Ctrl+click</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd+click</kbd> in Mac) behaviour.

Are there any such values for `target` attribute or are there any other attribute which can set such property to the links (`<a ...>`)?

Comment: I saw a question that suggest to emulate the keyboard input http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com" onclick="window.open('#','_blank');window.open(this.href,'_self');">
    linktext
</a>
```