# Stay current page active, when open external link

Tags: javascript, browser, external-links, current-page

I've been looking for a solution for a long time how to get, when I click to an external link in a page, it's opening in a new tab (same browser window) but the stay on current page.

target="_self" not a good solution.

Any idea?

**Thank You Everybody** in advance!

Comment: The closest I've come to an anwser myself is this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background Keep in mind it won't work for everyone, though.

Comment: Do you have any idea what can be the reason why it does not work for everyone? I tired this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZmvS/5/
In firedox can't open nothing, and in chrome it's open in new tab for me.

Comment: If use Ctrl + Click to Link it's work fine. I looking for maybe a js, which press ctrl automatic with link.