# HTML a href with target set to "_blank" without moving to the opened page

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, target

I would want to create an  tag with target attribute set to blank, but without actually moving me to the opened page, but rather staying on the page it was opened on.

Comment: That's typically a browser setting that you can't affect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a new tab in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background)

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <style></style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <a href="https://google.com/" trueblank="true" >Click Me</a>
      <script>
         var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
         links.forEach(function(each) {
            each.onclick = function(ev) {
                if(this.getAttribute("trueblank") == "true") {
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    window.open(this.href);
                 }
             }
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

following JS code below opens a new window on your current window and user remains on the first page yet

```
  window.open("https://www.w3schools.com", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
```