# JS open url in new tab on background

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, window

I want script to open in new tab url without focusing on it. I
tried:

```
window.open("https://www.google.com/").blur();
window.focus();
```

But it opens a new tab and focuses on google.com not on site with script. What's wrong?

edit:

This [Open a new tab in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background) is not resolving my question. Answer is too old and doesn't work anymore! Admins please read bold text: *"UPDATE: By version 41 of Google Chrome, initMouseEvent seemed to have a changed behavior, and so this answer no longer works."*

Comment: This is not possible in Google Chrome anymore. The behaviour is strictly controlled by the browser.

Comment: @squidee_ than how some advertisments open new tabs on background?

Comment: If you are talking about popups in a seperate window, this is still possible.

Comment: @squidee_ yeah. How to create so they will open on background?

Comment: Try this guide. [JavaScript.Info](https://javascript.info/popup-windows#example-a-minimalistic-window)

Comment: @squidee_ sorry, I meant new tab not window

Comment: tab != window ...

Comment: Could you send me a link where this happens? I've never experienced this.

Comment: @squidee_ it's local file. You can create blank html (or php if you have local server) file, add script tag and paste code from my question in it

Comment: I mean a link from where you have seen this before. I don't believe this is possible in Google Chrome, and most likely not possible in other major browsers.

Comment: @squidee_ I've seen it long time ago in old browsers so I don't remember where. I believe that it was done with answer from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background but as solution is not working anymore -  I'm trying to find out if there still is a way to do this.

Comment: Unfortunatley, this is not possible in modern browser. And if you could even find a work around, it would be very inconsistent and wouldn't work in many other browser.

Comment: @squidee_ I've created solution. It's not have the same logic as I wanted but it does same thing. It opens new tab with same url and old tab is redirected to google.com. There is a code: https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3y84zcm63.

Comment: The fact the accepted answer no longer works, doesn't mean your question isn't a duplicate. Maybe one of the other answers does work, or maybe someone needs to post an answer that this is no longer possible at all.