# MVC Html.ActionLink open new tab in the background

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my link and it works fine.

I need my link to open the new tab in the "Background". In other words, I don't want to see the new tab in focus.

```
 @Html.ActionLink(@durationInSecondsFormatted, "Index", "Player", new { id = item.Id }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-outline-success btn-sm", target = "_blank"})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a new tab in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. I need to do it using Html.ActionLink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is no way I found in html, Yes but when we click the link by pressing control key it opens the link in new background tab.