Open a new tab unfocused (WebGL - Unity)
I'm using Unity and build is for WebGL. I am able to open a URL as a new tab which is great, however as the new tab opens 'focused', it stops my WebGL application running until its tab is 're-focused'. I have the 'Run in background' setting 'ON' in Unity, however this does nothing in the build running in the browser.
My workaround is to open the URL as a new tab but 'Unfocused'. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?
I am using the following which is opening a new tab for the URL, just need to know what I can add to ensure it opens 'unfocused' or any other way to achieve this result:
Application.OpenURL(url);

By default, in an empty project, setting "Run in background" to true prevents an app from stopping when switching to another browser's tab (manually and via Application.OpenURL). It seems like there is a problem in your code.

Do it via JavaScript for full control (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background) then simply call it from Unity via a plug-in https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/web-interacting-code-example.html

Why has my question been downvoted? Have I done something wrong asking this question?

Well firstly, unity dosen't offer built in controll on Application.OpenURL("link"); wheter new tab focused or unfocused. You should use some javascript coed to execute opening new tab. Here is an example usage:
Create a new folder called Plugins in your Asset folder. then write this javascript code and save it;
function OpenUnfocusedTab(url) {
            var newTab = window.open(url, '_blank');
            if (newTab) {
                newTab.blur(); // Attempt to blur the focus on the new tab
                window.focus(); // Refocus on the current tab
            }
        }

then open a new script and use that javascript function like this;
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void OpenUnfocusedTab(string url);

public void OpenURLUnfocused(string url)
{
    #if UNITY_WEBGL && !UNITY_EDITOR
    OpenUnfocusedTab(url); //this part will be work on build
    #else
    Application.OpenURL(url); // this part is for editor
    #endif
}

I hope this will be work for your case !
