# Want to stay on current tab

Tags: javascript

How do I stay in current tab when opening a new tab using javascript?

I am using this
    
    var myWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');
    myWindow.focus();

But it is redirect to a new tab, I want to stay in current tab

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background). I don't think its legally possible to do so. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897430/prevent-window-open-from-focusing) suggests a chrome extension API.

Answer (score 1):

You can stay on same page by following ways :

```
window.location.replace(url);
```

or

```
window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: This is open a url in a same tab. I want to open a url in a new tab but stay on current page.