# Opening link in new tab in HTML

Tags: html

By setting target="_blank" it opens the page in a new tab but also automatically switches to the newly opened tab

```
 <p> <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" target = "_blank"> ask </a> </p>
```

when I click on ask, it opens in a new tab and switches to a new tab, how do I prevent switching to new tab.

I'm new to HTML so excuse me if the question is silly.

Comment: use `target="_self"` to open on the same page OR do not use target at all :)

Comment: I want it to open in new page but not automatically switch to the new page

Comment: You can use javascript check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897430/prevent-window-open-from-focusing

Comment: Yes, that answers my question, thank you!